# I can't use flash in playframework's views

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit

This is my view's code:

```
@(title:String)(conten:Html)(implicit lang:Lang, flash:Flash)

<html>
  <head>
    <title>.: @title :.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
      @flash.get("message").getOrElse("Welcome ;)")
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

But in my controller when i try this one:

```
def main = Action { implicit req =>
   Ok(views.html.main("First Page"))
}
```

I get this error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter flash: play.api.mvc.Flash
```

If I've understood correclty, in this case the "request2flash" method ( from Controller ) must create an implicit flash value... but why It doesn't work?

In another case when I try this one:

```
def main = Action { implicit req =>
   implicit val flash = req.flash
   Ok(views.html.main("First Page"))
}
```

I get this error:

```
ambiguous implicit values:
 both method request2flash in trait Controller of type (implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)play.api.mvc.Flash
 and value flash of type play.api.mvc.Flash
 match expected type play.api.mvc.Flash
```

### UPDATE

I'm using Typesafe Activator(1.2.8) with Scala 2.11.1 and Play 2.3.3.

### Apology

Please forgive me. I had 2 object with similar path and one of those hasn't "implicit" definination for request argument. I released that after 4 hours. Thanks of all.

Comment: What version of Play are you using? I've created test case with 2.2 and it works pretty fine with both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem with Scala 2.11.2 and Play 2.3.3. The following code compiles for me, showing that the implicits are working:

```
object App extends Controller {
  def flashy = Action { implicit req =>
  val flash = implicitly[Flash]
  Ok("")
}
```

There is a way to get your code to compile. Implicits are just a second argument list, so you can supply them explicitly:

```
def main = Action { req =>
  Ok(views.html.main("First Page")(request2lang(req), request2flash(req)))
}
```

Of course, this is no substitute for finding and fixing the cause of the problem!

UPDATE:

I just noticed that you are calling  `views.html.main` instead of `views.html.index`. This won't compile, since `views.html.main` has an extra argument list `(content: Html)`. This is no doubt the cause of your problem.